# Converting a percentage whole number in one field to a decimal in another field in Adobe Livecycle

Tags: livecycle, livecycle-designer

I'm creating a budget template in Livecycle Designer.
I have a field where users can enter a percentage as a number (for example if you want to enter 75%, just enter 75). 
I'd like another numfield box to take this number and convert it to .75

Can I do this across num fields or do I have to do it one box (where a user enters 75 and it turns into .75 automatically).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to enter integer numbers in the numeric field then that can easily be done by just taking a numeric field and then simply entering this javascript in the "exit event" of the field as:

```
var value1=this.rawValue;
this.rawValue="."+value1;
```